# How to send real time response from server to client using Node.js express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket, socket.io

on post request server is generating data after few seconds, these are almost 1000 to 10000 entries. Currently i'm saving data into csv file and it's working fine. how can i pas data to client with json array.

Name and Age variable getting data after few seconds

````
app.post('/', (req, res) => {

// currently passing to results.csv. its working fine i want to send this real time (Name and age) data to client.

const stream = createWriteStream('./results.csv', { flags: 'a', encoding: 'utf8' })

 // Append evaluation from response to file

 stream.write(`${Name}, ${Age}\n`)

// example data:  Patrick, 32

// End stream to avoid accumulation

 stream.end()
})

res.send() only send first row but Name and age variable getting update after after each 10 seconds

app.listen(port, () => {
 console.log("App is running on port " + port);
}); ```
````

Comment: have you tried res.json()

Comment: Yes it's sending only first row

Comment: Where are the `Name` and `Age` variables in `stream.write` taken?

Comment: @Fide string value

Answer (score 0):

To parse data into json array, you would have to read the stream before sending the data. Example:

```
let rows = []
fs.createReadStream('./results.csv')
   .pipe(parse())
   .on("error", (error) => console.error(error))
   .on("data", (row) => rows.push(row))
   .on("end", () => res.send(rows))
```

But if you want to send the csv file data, do something like this:

```
return res.sendFile("./results.csv", options, (err) => {
    if(error) console.error(error)
    console.log("File has been sent")
})
```

NOTE: The parse() method used in the first example is gotten from the [fast-csv](https://c2fo.github.io/fast-csv/docs/parsing/methods) package.

Also, using a package like `fast-csv` makes it easy to write data to the csv file while setting `headers:true`. Trying to read the data, the `parse` method has to be informed of the headers already set in order to use those values for the json keys.